# Some pop-ups (when clicked on links) in OWA are blocked by certain browsers, is it mandatory to resolve this

Tags: outlook-web-app, office-store

When some links are clicked in our Outlook Web Add-in, certain browsers are blocking pop-ups & are expecting the user to manually allow them.  As a result the Add-in is being rejected for this. May i know why it is mandatory to resolve this?

After all the browser is just taking confirmation from the user to open the link.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for the office-store support (which we aren't).

Comment: They have directed me here to ask this question.

they say "Got a question you want to ask the validation team? Connect with us on StackOverflow" . (it is a clickable link redirecting to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-store)